# How to apply post-processing EffectComposer render passes without clearing previous render passes?

Tags: three.js, 3d, render, post-processing

In three.js I have a red plane in the background and a rotating white cube in the foreground. I'm trying to add a `TAARenderPass` to the cube while leaving the background plane untouched. However, adding the `TAARenderPass` (as well as `BokehPass`, `SAOPass`, and other common post-processing effects) clears everything behind it and the red plane disappears.

I've dug through similar questions on here and tried `renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 )`, `renderer.autoClear = false`, and `renderer.autoClearColor = false`. This is how everything is set up now:

```
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true, antialias: true } );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  // EffectComposer
  const params = { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat, stencilBuffer: false };
  const renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, params );
  effectComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer , renderTarget );
  effectComposer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  // Render Passes
  const renderPassBg = new THREE.RenderPass( sceneBg , camera );

  const renderPassFg = new THREE.RenderPass( sceneFg , camera );
  renderPassFg.clear = false;

  const taaRenderPass = new THREE.TAARenderPass( sceneFg, camera );
  taaRenderPass.clear = false;

  const copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
  copyPass.renderToScreen = true;

  effectComposer.addPass( renderPassBg );
  effectComposer.addPass( renderPassFg );
  // effectComposer.addPass( taaRenderPass );
  effectComposer.addPass( copyPass );
```

There's a full CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/eyver/pen/GLyWOq).

Everything works as expected (minus the post-processing effects) when `effectComposer.addPass( taaRenderPass )` is commented out. But when the commenting is removed, only the white cube renders.

How do I get the red plane to render behind `taaRenderPass`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can you try inserting a `copyPass` with `renderToScreen = false` before the taa pass?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried adding a second `copyPass` with `renderToScreen = false` to the CodePen linked in the OP and did the `addPass(secondCopyPass)` immediately before the `addPass(taaRenderPass)` but still the same issue - the `taaRenderPass` clears everything that comes before it. Just to be sure, is there a chance I misinterpreted how to implement your suggestion?

Comment: Ahh.. just realized it's TAA (temporal antialias) pass. TAA requires rendering the screen space velocities to a framebuffer for use in the antialias.. so that's probably why the buffer is getting nuked.

Can you switch to FXAAntialias?